# What does "ever" mean in this sentence?

Tags: vocabulary

> A passion for books and the words inside them saved me from ***ever***
> knowing a moment’s loneliness during library hours.
>
> -- [*The Power of Words*](http://thisibelieve.org/essay/4210/) by Benita Porter

What do I have to pick up for the ‘ever’ on [OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/ever) or [Merriam-Webster’s Learner’s Dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/ever)?

Comment: If "saved me from ever knowing" was rewritten as "meant that I never knew", would you understand? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Ever* means "always", or "for the entirety of time".

Consequently

> A passion for books and the words inside them saved me from ever knowing a moment’s loneliness.

means that "A passion for books and the words inside them" are responsible for the author never "knowing a moment's loneliness".

The sentence then ends with an additional time constraint:

> A passion for books and the words inside them saved me from ever knowing a moment’s loneliness **during library hours**.

What this caveat does is it constrains "never" to mean "whilst the library was open".

So in conclusion, the sentence as a whole means that whilst the library was open for business, "a passion for books and the words inside them" saved the author from "knowing a moment's loneliness".

Comment: One way to rephrase this: "Because I was passionate about books, I never (not even for a moment) felt lonely during library hours."